# Definition of a Euclidean domain

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, normed-spaces, principal-ideal-domains, euclidean-domain

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_domain):

> Let $R$ be an integral domain. A Euclidean function on $R$ is a function
>   $$f:R\setminus \{0\}\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}^+$$
>    satisfying the following fundamental division-with-remainder property:
>
> If $a$ and $b$ are in $R$ and $b$ is nonzero, then there are $q$ and $r$ in $R$ such that $a = bq + r$ and either $r = 0$ or $f(r) < f(b)$.

What is the motivation for the requirement $f(r)<f(b)$? (What is it good for?)

I immediately think of the [Euclidean algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm), which ensures us that the process of finding the $\gcd(a,b)$ must end. Is there a similar reason for $f(r)<f(b)$, to ensure that "some process" ends? I also thought about the proof that every Euclidean domain is a [PID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_ideal_domain), where the proof chooses $b$ minimum so that $f(r)\not <f(b)\Rightarrow r=0$.

Comment: You cannot decrease for ever with natural numbers. That's important. So at some point you must get $r=0$.  To ensure that you do not have cycling you should mover down on an ordered set. You will be guaranteed to stop if there are no infinite decreasing chains in that set.

Comment: If you omitted the requirement $f(r<f(b)$, then, regardless of what ring $R$ and function $f$ you considered, you could always find, for any given $a$ and $b$, a solution to $a=bq+r$, namely $q=0$ and $r=a$.  So the "Euclidean" requirement would become vacuous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is exactly the generalization of the standard division algorithm for integers. Suppose we have $n, m \in \mathbb{Z}$. We learn early on that there exists a unique $q \in \mathbb{Z}$ (called the quotient) and a unique $r \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that 
$$
n = mq + r, \ \ \ \ 0 \leq r < m.
$$
The point is that we have a remainder $r$ that is *less* than the number $m$ which we divided  $n$ by.

To generalize this to an arbitrary ring, where there is no a priori ordering, we need to find some condition to replace $0 \leq r < m$. This is where the Euclidean function (sometimes called a norm) comes in. Then, we may generalize the above division algorithm to hold for any nonzero $m = b, n = a \in R$, where $R$ is a general ring. The condition that our remainder is less than our divisor, $b$,  is now replaced with the statement that $f(r) < f(b)$ or $r = 0$.